# What license are the Ubuntu wallpapers distributed under?

Tags: desktop-background, license

I haven't found the licensing data for the **Forever by Shady S** wallpaper, which would be very helpful as I am interested in uploading it to a Wiki, hence a CC-BY-SA license would be desirable.

Comment: You can find the liscence within the package. Or look up the package. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/wallpaper which links to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/w/wallpaper/wallpaper_0.1-1ubuntu1/wallpaper.copyright

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The community wallpapers are distributed under a CC-BY-SA 3.0 license.

```
Upstream-Name: ubuntu-wallpapers
Source: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-wallpapers

Files: *
Copyright: 2010-2013 Ubuntu community contributors
License: CC-BY-SA 3.0
```

This information is on disk in `/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-wallpapers-trusty/copyright`