# Can I use a community wallpaper from Lubuntu 15.04 in 14.04

Tags: desktop-background

Re the wallpaper competition for Lubuntu 15.04 in The Lubuntu Blog, can I download one in Lubuntu 14.04/

Comment: Yes, since the wallpapers are shared under a [CC-BY-SA license](http://askubuntu.com/a/519239/158442).

Answer (score 1):

Actually just install the ubuntu wallpapers

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-version-of-ubuntu-here
```

Then symlink it into Lubuntu Wallpapers directory

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/backgrounds /usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers/community-wallpapers
```

Now you should see a community-wallpapers directory when choosing images.

:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. You'll need `sudo` to put the image into `/usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers`. But that's about it. Then you should see the new wallpaper as a choice when you next open `Customize Look and Feel` in Menu > Preferences.

Comment: response in terminal is 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Do I enter 'sudo' first then '/usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers' ? The response to this is 'Is a directory'