# ubuntu-wallpapers: the copyright file doesn't seem to always contain the license with specific distribs

Tags: desktop-background, license

This is is a follow-up to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438419/understanding-the-copyright-file-in-ubuntu-wallpapers). In short:

- I would like to collect all the pictures from the various Ubuntu wallpapers together with their appropriate credits/license.
- Thanks to the answer, I can interpret the content of the file `/usr/share/doc/<package id>/copyright` which contains the license info for the files installed in `/usr/share/backgrounds/` for each distrib.

This works fine with many packages but with some packages (quite old ones, apparently) I can't find some/any of the image files in the `copyright` file. For example, `ubuntu-wallpapers-maverick` contains 17 images:

```
> dpkg -L ubuntu-wallpapers-maverick | grep jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Aeg_by_Tauno_Erik.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Blue_box_number_2_by_orb9220.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Blue_by_ElSlunko.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Bubbles_by_JanneM.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Crocosmia_by_sirpecangum.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Feather_by_quinn.anya.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Fern_by_aalex04.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Life_by_Paco_Espinoza.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Liquid_glass_by_matthileo.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Mirada_Perduda_by_Marxicoli.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Morning_II_by_Tadas_N.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Primer_Amanecer_2010_by_letoloke.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Ropey_Photo_by_Bob_Farrell.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Serenity_Enchanted_by_sirpecangum.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Smile_by_quinn.anya.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Spiral_by_firas.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/Waterchain_by_Poje_Mario.jpg
```

But the file `/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-wallpapers-maverick/copyright` does not contain `Aeg_by_Tauno_Erik.jpg` (nor `Aeg` or `Tauno`). Same for the other images.

The format seems to be regular, am I missing something? Is there another way to find the credits related to these images?

---

Additional details: I wrote [a script](https://github.com/erwanm/indie-coding/blob/main/collect-ubuntu-wallpapers.sh) which installs all the `ubuntu-wallpapers-*` packages one by one to extract the images provided the license is found. There might be bugs but the script doesn't find the images filename for more than half the images overall.

Comment: Checking [the package copyright file](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/u/ubuntu-wallpapers/ubuntu-wallpapers_18.04.1-0ubuntu1/copyright) there's a `Files: *` section which will cover the files that are not matched by more specific sections, and it says "2010-2016 Ubuntu community contributors
License: CC-BY-SA-3.0" which I believe should cover this file

Comment: @muru oh right, I didn't realize that this `*` could be interpreted this way. So for any image not listed, one should cite *Nathaniel McCallum, Daniel Holbach and Ubuntu community contributors* as authors in this case? It's a bit strange because very often the filename contains the author's name.

Comment: I think Nathaniel McCallum and Daniel Holbach did the packaging work and only take copyright for those parts, and for the pictures it would be "Ubuntu community contributors". I'm not sure how it came to be like it, but perhaps during the early days of the wallpaper contests they were more lax about the copyright specification.

Comment: @muru Thanks for this point, it might be correct indeed. Ideally I'd like to have confirmation since CC-BY-SA requires citing the author and it's not completely how to cite in this case.